# Getting a hidden password input

Tags: python, passwords, user-input

You know how in Linux when you try some Sudo stuff it tells you to enter the password and, as you type, nothing is shown in the terminal window (the password is not shown)?

Is there a way to do that in Python? I'm working on a script that requires so sensitive info and would like for it to be hidden when I'm typing it.

In other words, I want to get the password from the user without showing the password.

Comment: For Tkinter-specific solutions (referring to a Tkinter text entry field rather than the standard input), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416486.

Comment: If you specifically want `*` or other symbols to appear for each character of input, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805078 (but some answers here also cover that case).

Answer (score 557, accepted):

Use [`getpass.getpass()`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass):

```
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
```

An optional prompt can be passed as parameter; the default is `"Password: "`.

Note that this function requires a proper terminal, so it can turn off echoing of typed characters – see [“GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal” when running from IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878741/getpasswarning-can-not-control-echo-on-the-terminal-when-running-from-idle) for further details.

Comment: will work, but how can one be careful of a "hacker" that will make a copy of the script and then comment out the line that requires user password?

Comment: @asf107: If the hacker can edit the source code, there are other problems to worry about.

Comment: @asf107 - The idea behind requesting a password is so that you can pass it along to authenticate with something (IE, I'm using this to request a password to authenticate with an online server). If a hacker commented out the line, the program would simply fail because the server wouldn't be authenticated with anymore. The idea behind using `getpass()` is so that nobody can look at the source code and find out your password just by reading it, and nobody can get your password by just staring over your shoulder and reading your password off the screen when you type it in.

Comment: Beware of `getpass`. When on an incompatible terminal it will *show* the password and the documentation does not indicate how to check that in advance (e.g. to try other means to get the password) or to simply fail rather than asking a password with terminal echo.

Comment: @callegar Any source to the information that you shared in your comment?

Comment: @RomeoSierra See the [documentation of `GetPassWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.GetPassWarning). You can use the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) to turn the warning into an error and catch it if you want to protect against this.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yup.. that's the missing piece...

Comment: @RomeoSierra tried that, but with no success. The waring comes once the password prompt has already been given to the user. Can be tested using the Spyder console. Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: @callegar That's rather weird, since the [source code first emits the warning and then prints the prompt](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d341098c59e75821958c40aeb921dd41209e51f7/Lib/getpass.py#L120-L126). If you turn the warning into an error, it should never print the prompt. Moreover, the code also prints "Warning: Password input may be echoed." before showing the prompt.

Answer (score 206):

```
import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
```

[getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) works on Linux, Windows, and Mac.

Comment: "Password: " (with a space after the colon) is the default prompt, so there's often no need to specify it in the call to getpass.getpass().

Comment: getpass is a standard library module that's been around since at least Python 2.5

Comment: this gave me an error `Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\getpass.py", line 92
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
` in the IDLE, but worked well in the command prompt, found the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878741/getpasswarning-can-not-control-echo-on-the-terminal-when-running-from-idle)

Comment: getpass() Does not work with IDLE. Is there another way to achieve this without getpass()?

Comment: To have the prompt is on the stderr (you will also need `import sys`): `getpass.getpass(`<string>`,sys.stderr)`

Comment: @Brendan, if you are using IDLE or another IDE, consider `from easygui import passwordbox` followed by `password = passwordbox("Enter password:")`.

Answer (score 21):

This code will print an asterisk instead of every letter.

```
import sys
import msvcrt

passwor = ''
while True:
    x = msvcrt.getch()
    if x == '\r':
        break
    sys.stdout.write('*')
    passwor +=x

print '\n'+passwor
```

Comment: this is windows only but at least it's not repeating the `getpass` answer. Good

Comment: wont handle backspaces.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your code is for Python 2.x, but this does not work for me. I'm running Python 3.x. First error I got was a TypeError for the 'passwor += x' line. It said: "can't convert bytes object to str implicitly". I changed the line so that I explicitly cast x to string such as: "password += str(x)". But the code still does not work. When I run it, it doesn't prompt me for input, it just prints the asterisk forever.

Comment: @Larper It is for Python 2, see the last line of the code

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Some modifications were required for this code to be compatible with Python 3. Have submitted a modified code edit. Hope it gets approved :)

Comment: DON't DO THIS...  people have already done it...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67327327/701532

Answer (score 4):

Updating on the answer of @Ahmed ALaa

```
# import msvcrt
import getch

def getPass():
    passwor = ''
    while True:
        x = getch.getch()
        # x = msvcrt.getch().decode("utf-8")
        if x == '\r' or x == '\n':
            break
        print('*', end='', flush=True)
        passwor +=x
    return passwor

print("\nout=", getPass())
```

msvcrt us only for windows, but [getch](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) from PyPI should work for both (I only tested with linux).
You can also comment/uncomment the two lines to make it work for windows.

Comment: DON't DO THIS... people have already done it... stackoverflow.com/a/67327327/701532

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the pwinput module which works on both Windows and Linux.
It replaces the char with '*' (by default) and backspace works.

```py
import pwinput

password = pwinput.pwinput(prompt='Password: ')
```

You can, optionally, pass a different `mask` character as well.

```py
import pwinput

password = pwinput.pwinput(prompt='Password: ', mask='')
```

See the [pwinput documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pwinput/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code based off the code offered by **@Ahmed ALaa**

Features:

- Works for passwords up to 64 characters
- Accepts backspace input
- Outputs `*` character `(DEC: 42 ; HEX: 0x2A)` instead of the input character

Demerits:

- Works on Windows only

The function `secure_password_input()` returns the password as a `string` when called. It accepts a *Password Prompt* string, which will be displayed to the user to type the password

```
def secure_password_input(prompt=''):
    p_s = ''
    proxy_string = [' '] * 64
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write('\x0D' + prompt + ''.join(proxy_string))
        c = msvcrt.getch()
        if c == b'\r':
            break
        elif c == b'\x08':
            p_s = p_s[:-1]
            proxy_string[len(p_s)] = " "
        else:
            proxy_string[len(p_s)] = "*"
            p_s += c.decode()

    sys.stdout.write('\n')
    return p_s
```

Comment: DON't DO THIS... people have already done it... stackoverflow.com/a/67327327/701532

Comment: @anthony I just found it wiser to write a **16 line function** with **standard imports**. Also, I get to see what's running under the hood and I can customize things as required

Comment: Yes customise it for yourself... but what about other users?  Also from personal experience, even handing stars can get complicated fast, dealing with control characters, unicode, kill lines, or even a simple... turning off echo (tab of backspace at start of input).
The better why do it is to focus instead on the ability to use a 'password helper', like "system-ask-password" which already provides a 'star password input'.   SSH and SUDO can both do this!   The user can then select their own way of inputting passwords, be it with stars, or from a password manager, or some other source!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using **pyautogui**. Pyautogui is a great GUI automation module. It can access the mouse, keyboard, find images on screen (uses Pillow), and also display alert boxes, confirmation boxes, and buttons. In this case, the function that I suggest is password(). For example:

```
import pyautogui

password = pyautogui.password('Enter password: ') #password hidden with *

print(password)
```

If you want to learn more about how pyautogui can be used for buttons, confirmation boxes, and alert boxes, or for any other things, you can check out the information [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/). [Full documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org).