# How do I make a password input on python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting command-line password input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202224/getting-command-line-password-input-in-python)

I was wondering how to make a password input on python, if you dont know what I'm saying well I mean like if I typed in something like "hello" it will add "*****" instead as if you were typing in a password

Comment: At the command line? It's worth noting that if that is the case, the standard for Linux tools is to not print anything, not printing stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html). You can use it as:

```
from getpass import getpass
passwd = getpass()
```

It doesn't print stars, though.