# Python giving list out of bounds but it shows both elements in the list

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to make a simple log in program using python (still fairly new to it), and I have the log in information stored in a text file for the user to match in order to successfully log in. Whenever I run it it says "list index out of range" but I'm able to print out the value of that element in the list, which is where I'm confused. I am trying to add the first line (username) and the second line (password) in the file to the list to compare to the user inputted values for each field, but am unable to compare them.

```
def main():
    username = getUsername()
    password = getPassword()
    authenticateUser(username, password)


def getUsername():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")

    return username


def getPassword():
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")

    return password


def authenticateUser(username, password):
    credentials = []
    with open("account_information.txt") as f:
        content = f.read()
        credentials.append(content)

    if(username == credentials[0] and password == credentials[1]):
        print("Login Successful!")

    else:
        print("Login Failed")



main()
```

Comment: You only append one item to `credentials`. Why would you expect `credentials[1]` to be a thing?

Comment: Try printing the value of `credentials` after you have read in the file and you should see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I suggest to **think next** about the [actual password input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9202224/2932052) and about [storing passwords other than in plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7014953/2932052)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [readline](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to get your infos in a list :

```
def authenticateUser(username, password):
    credentials = []
    with open("account_information.txt") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
```

Using this, accordingly to what you describe, `content[0]` will be your username and `content[1]` your password.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that if I did just f.read() it would give me each line in the file to add to the list. Using readlines() gave me the username and password, I just had to strip the newline for it to work.

Comment: @iFlo: I fixed the off-by-one error in the description that was introduced by adding the readline link.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the python documentation at [*7.2.1. Methods of File Objects*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), you'll see

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string or bytes object

You will see that f.read() is not the function you are looking for. try f.readlines() instead to put the content in a list of lines.

> If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use list(f) or f.readlines().

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what is in your `account_information.txt`, `file.read` might not be the function you want to use.

Indeed, `read` will return a *string*, that is a list of all the *characters* in the file. So if you have your username and password on two separate lines for instance

```
foo
H0weSomeP4ssworD
```

you may instead use [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readlines) to parse your file into a list of strings where each element is a line within the file.

Comment: ...splitting the file content afterwards would be another option ;)

Answer (score -1):

After having *"your problem solved"*, I invite you to come back to your problem description:

> Python giving list out of bounds but it shows both elements in the list

What have you learned besides the fact that you have used the wrong method? I hope also something about your diagnostic skills. How should you print out a list to see how many items it contains?

If you do it like this

```
items = []
items.append("hello\nworld")
for i in items:
    print(i)
```

you'll see:

```
hello
world
```

If you therefore deduce to have 2 items in the list, is this correct?

And python definitely reports that you're accessing the list **out of bounds**. You saw the conflict between your and python's perspective.

I think you should at least have learned using [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=len#len) for out-of-bounds diagnostics today.