# input password with astrix

Tags: python, getchar

I want to read char one by one and show to astrix `*`.
Characters can be showed as `*`, but I cannot exit by pushing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This is my code:

```
import sys, tty, termios

def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        sys.stdout.write('*')
    except:
        print "ex"
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN,old_settings)
    return ch
```

If I input <kbd>Enter</kbd> where `ch = sys.stdin.read(1)`, what is the return value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202236/4737952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getpass.getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) to prompt a user for a password. But note that `getpass` module does not show asterisks for unix password prompts.

As for the second part of the question - `sys.stdin.read(1)` returns `\n` or `\r` for Enter input, it depends on a terminal you're using.

And, finally, I made an example how to use your function to read until CR or LF:

```
while True:', '\n']: break
    ch = getch()
    if ch in ['\r', '\n']: break
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

If you really need to show asterisks even for unix, that's the way.

Comment: OMG! This is exactly what I want to do! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to read passwords from the user more securely, check out `getpass` module.

It can be simply imported and used like shown below. But keep in mind that it doesn't show asterik.

```
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass('Your message')
```

Return value of `sys.stdin.read(1)` is entirely depending on the console you are using.

Comment: Thank you for answering!