# getpass() function not taking password in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

getpass() function is not letting the user input for password option in pycharm.
I am trying to login to a website using selenium and the login credentials i am passing from console but after entering the ID using input() function, the input option for password is not coming

My code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from getpass import getpass
username = input("enter your amazon id")
paswd = getpass("enter your password: ")

chrome_path = "C:/Users/shashshe/Downloads/chromedriver_win32   /chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://alexa.amazon.in/spa/index.html')
driver.find_element_by_id('ap_email').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('ap_password').send_keys(paswd)
driver.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit').click()

time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: you replace every character for * directly in a conole ... Answer number 4 here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202224/getting-command-line-password-input-in-python> but I think that if you run it in debug / in console it will work  ( answer on your question from comments )