# Prevent displaying the user entered input in Python 3.7 or Latest Version?

Tags: python

a =input()

print(a)

Now if the user enters:

a =6

6

The output displayed should be:

a =

6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting command-line password input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202224/getting-command-line-password-input-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [getpass.getpass()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html). Here's an example I wrote in Python3.9.2 64-Bit

```
from getpass import getpass

a = getpass("a = ")
print(a)
```