# Hide input password when typing in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, passwords

I need to write a code for  an input password, like when I need to type the password it needs to layer the password like this *****.
Notice that to code I'm using **PyCharm**.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202236/9415337

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting command-line password input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202224/getting-command-line-password-input-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy way to do this. However, you can use a couple of modules to create a similar function.

1. PYAUTOGUI

```py
import pyautogui

paswrd = pyautogui.password(text='', title='', default='', mask='*')
```

This opens a small window in which you can enter your password. Here, the password will be displayed as you want: it will use `*`s.

2. GETPASS

```py
import getpass

paswrd = getpass.getpass()
```

This will allow the user to enter a password normally, and the password won't show. It will be hidden. **THIS ONLY WORKS IN THE TERMINAL, NOT SHELL**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getpass` module to hide your password:

```
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass(prompt='Input your password: ') # the default prompt is 'Password: '
```

This won't replace it with `*` but at least you can't see the password.

Note: It will not work in the shell. Thanks to @PilotDude

Comment: However, it should be noted that getpass doesn't work in the shell.

Comment: If using Spyder IDE, you'll get the following warning: QtConsole does not support password mode, the text you type will be visible.

Comment: @Ben I think it only works in the actual python console.