# How can i get the terminal to not show what the user has inputted in python?

Tags: python, string, user-interface, input, terminal

I am writing a terminal based project for a course using python. At the moment my code looks like this:

```py
user_input = input("Please input your age here")
print(f"Your age is {user_input} years old")
```

And in the terminal looks like:

```
Please input your age here
25
Your age is 25 years old
```

I want to hide where the user has put 25, ie. I want the terminal readout to look like;

```
Please input your age here
Your age is 25 years old
```

It may not be possible but as the user interface s the terminal I want it to look as clean as possible

Comment: Treat it as a password so the input is hidden, please see marked duplicate

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, not sure how to treat it as a password, also not sure what you mean by marked duplicate, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `getpass`:

```py
from getpass import getpass
user_input = getpass("Please input your age here")
print(f"Your age is {user_input} years old")
```

> [Getting a hidden password input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202224/getting-a-hidden-password-input)

Comment: Obvious duplicate, you even pasted a link to the dupe, why not vote to close?

Comment: @0stone0, because I don't have 3k rep. I upvoted your comment on the duplicate. I'm posting an answer because OP asked a question, it's not against the rules to post an answer on a possible duplicate

Comment: hello, i wasnt aware of a duplicate question, if i posted more than once im sorry, pretty new here and first time posting, just couldnt find an answer elsewhere

Comment: @lisa-underwater that's okay :), the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) may be worth reading before posting another question