# How to preview text in tkinter entry (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

So how do I make it so before my user enters anything into the text box it has a preview saying "Type your name" or something along those lines?
[e.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSObB.png)

```
userName = Entry(text="Username", font = ('Arial', 15), bg = 'white').place(relx = 0.55, rely = 0.35)
#userName.insert(0, "User name")
password = Entry(text="Password", font = ('Arial', 15), bg = 'white',show = '•').place(relx = 0.55, rely = 0.43)
#password.insert(0, "Password")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = Text(parent, width=40, height=10)
text.insert('1.0', 'here is my text to insert')
```

For more info see: [the tk docs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html)

Comment: thanks but it says nonetype has no attribute insert

Comment: Without seeing your code it's very difficult to help. Either edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: ok edited the question

Comment: Inserting first and placing second will probably do the trick.

Comment: but how do i make it so when they start typing it goes away, also for the password thing i want it to not show what they type so insert doesnt really work for that

Comment: For your first question take a look at the question linked by jasonharper in his comment to your question, especially the last answer by Daniyal Ahmad. For the password thing to work a simple Google search gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416486/how-to-create-a-password-entry-field-using-tkinter), look for Brōtsyorfuzthrāx's answer.